# NFS – pemission denied

Tags: linux, nfs

This is my NFS server:

```
$more /proc/fs/nfs/exports 
# Version 1.1
# Path Client(Flags) # IPs
/mnt    192.168.1.0/24(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,uuid=1ba3cbb4:bf2245d2:8af07796:d5961c5e,sec=1)
/   192.168.1.0/24(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,fsid=0,uuid=1ba3cbb4:bf2245d2:8af07796:d5961c5e,sec=1)
/mnt/raid   192.168.1.0/24(rw,root_squash,all_squash,sync,wdelay,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=100,uuid=1beff30a:b9af4535:959c9
b60:1318400e,sec=1)

$more /etc/exports 
/mnt/raid   192.168.1.0/24(rw,all_squash,sync,anonuid=1000,anongid=100,no_subtree_check)
```

My client:

```
$vim /etc/fstab 
192.168.1.20:/mnt/raid /mnt/raid        nfs     auto,rw 0       0
```

I can open the mounted directory in the client, I can see and read files but when I want to paste or create, I get

> ```
> permission denied
> ```

I just want a full sharing on my LAN. Did I miss something?

Comment: Can user `uid=1000` or group `gid=100` paste or create files in `/mnt/raid/` locally (on the server)? Check permissions.

Comment: apparently not, i need to do a sudo to do a touch.

Answer (score 1):

From [`man 5 exports`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports):

> `all_squash`
>   Map all uids and gids to the anonymous user. Useful for NFS-exported public FTP directories, news spool directories, etc. The opposite option is `no_all_squash`, which is the default setting.

These ids are set with `anonuid` and `anongid` options.

Make sure the directory inside `/mnt/raid/` where you try to write via NFS is (locally) writable for this `uid` or `gid`.

Comment: Ok thx. The mounting file was owned by my user, but the target disk was mounted with root.
I add "user" param in the fstab. And a chown for the mounting point.
Thx a lot :)

Comment: I know, i just don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer. I will do it a soon as i could.